# Symfony2 The controller for URI is not callable

Tags: symfony, uri

I got this controller

```
namespace myprojects\StreamBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class StreamController extends Controller
{    
    public function showMultiAction($text)
    {
    }

    public function showGamingtvAction($text)
    {
    }
}
```

And my routing.yml

```
stream_gamingtv:
    pattern:  /gamingtv/{text}
    defaults: { _controller: StreamBundle:Stream:showGamingtv }


stream_multi:
    pattern:  /{text}
    defaults: { _controller: StreamBundle:Stream:showMulti }
```

Symfony2 is generating the links, but when i clicked over it shows me the error.

> The controller for URI "/gamingtv/SugusSusana" is not callable.

I have two similar controllers that work, but don't understand why it does not

Comment: Did you clear your cache? APC cache?

Comment: also post full code of your controller (you can omit other actions).

Comment: I clear my cache, im working with xCache but previously i add another controller and it works fine :/

Comment: Clear your xCache. Some files can be used from cache while new files will be added.

Comment: i added the controller, and add another action that works fine

Comment: Did you clear your xCache?

Comment: Ill try to do it now.I will keep you informed.ty michael

Comment: So showMultiAction works (in the same class) but showGamingtvAction does not?  Strange.  Is it possible that you have another /gamingtv/{text} route defined in a different file?

Comment: Nope, this is the unique route.

On local it works, all routes works fine but in production server not. @MichaelSivolobov how can i clear the xCache cache?

Comment: Is the xCache, i disabled and it worked then, how i can clear xCache cache?

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual class name of your bundle?

I'm going to guess that `StreamBundle` is not the correct bundle name. They are usually prefixed by your top-level namespace so something more like `myprojectsStreamBundle:Stream:showGamingtv` would seem to be more likely.

Comment: What's the output you get from `php app/console router:debug`?

Comment: Peter, the route its ok. The problem is the xCache, i disable it and the route works.

Then i just need know how clear the xCache cache.

Comment: Seems like that's just `xcache_clear_cache()` which, assuming it's configured correctly, you could run like so `php -r "xcache_clear_cache();"`